# Make non graphical TTY more compatible with XTerm

Tags: virtual-console

I have a machine where I do not need/want Xwindows, intead I just use terminal in text only mode. There is a problem, ttys are very limited compared to XTerm/VTE terminals, i.e. only 16 colors, many key combinations are not possible, Shift+Left for example, some ANSII escape sequences do not work properly or at all, like secondary buffer exit escape sequence does not restore the screen contents. 
Hence the question: how can the non graphical terminal be made more compatible with XTerm/VTE terminals? i.e. xterm-color256 or high-color but without using X.

Comment: Are you talking about pure text mode? Or is it some kind of virtual system? And which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Have you considered to SSH to such a machine from a workstation with GUI?